# YII2 Custom validation is not working with custom function model rule

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-validation

I am trying to implement with custom function in model its not working i am not getting what's wrong in my code. i am trying to call with basic later i will put my condition.

Here is model code

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['mobile_number', 'required'],
            ['mobile_number', 'myfunction'],

        ];
    }

public function myfunction($attribute,$params)
    {
             $this->addError($attribute, 'You have already submitted');

    }
```

Here is controller code

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Createuser();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

its not assiging the error to a form-field.

```
Thanks in advance.
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem in my application, did you solved it? Have any ideas?

Comment: yes @Clyff i fixed that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code is fine. it was error with Dynamic Form validation.

Answer (score 3):

I guess the parameter named `mobile_number` does not exist in your data or it is an empty string, so try to add `'skipOnEmpty' => false` in your code.

Anyway, it works for me.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['mobile_number', 'required', 'skipOnEmpty' => false],
        ['mobile_number', 'myfunction', 'skipOnEmpty' => false],
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you are not extending the model class ? if so you need to put this :

```
$model->validate()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Model:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['mobile_number', 'required'],
        ['mobile_number', 'myfunction'],
    ];
}

public function myfunction($attribute,$params)
{
    $this->addError($attribute, 'You have already submitted');
    return false;   
}
```

And your controller:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Createuser();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save() && $model->validate()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: please enter first mobile number and then submit form then you can show error msg

Comment: i need to show while submitting  to a form-field
in this form also reseting. and pjax is not working.

Answer (score 0):

try this
in your controller

```
protected function performAjaxValidation($model = NULL) {

        if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
            echo json_encode(ActiveForm::validate($model));
            Yii::$app->end();
        }
    }

public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Createuser();
    $this->performAjaxValidation($model);
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save() && $model->validate()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```